# Reverse django admin custom url with reverse

Tags: django, django-admin

I have model admin view to which I added custom view like below. Then I'm using jQuery to upload a csv file.

```
def get_urls(self):
    urls = super(MyAdminView, self).get_urls()
    my_urls = [
        path('upload_csv/', self.upload_csv, name='upload_csv'),
    ]
    return my_urls + urls
```

My problem is that I don't know how to reverse url to that view in tests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in `redirect` or `reverse`

you can use

```
admin:app_name:upload_csv
```

or if no app is related to this url

```
admin:upload_csv
```